# When coming back to the homepage via <Link> or router.push() in NextJS, the page is empty on production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I have a problem when publishing a NextJS website to production with Vercel. On development, everything is working as intended:
I have a header on top of the website with a logotype and a language switcher, looking like that (simplified version of course):

```js
<header className="header">
  <div className="header__section">
    <h1 className="header__title">
      <Link href="/">{data.title}</Link>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div className="header__section">
    <div className="header__languages">
      {["fr", "en"].map((lang, index) => (
        <div key={`lang-${index}`} className="header__language" onClick={() => router.push({ pathname, query }, asPath, { locale: lang })}>
          {lang.toUpperCase()}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Everything works perfectly well on development, but on production, on the homepage and **only** the homepage, the page loads once but if I come back to it using the link on the site title or changing the language on the homepage and then coming back to the original language, the page appears completely empty, with no error on the console.

After a few tests, it appears that the homepage data is not fetched again if I come back to it, making the page completely empty.

[How the code looks after coming back to the homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb9Cb.png)

Do you have any idea what might cause this? I tried multiple things, emptying the whole homepage except for the logotype, removing all data fetching from the `getStaticProps()` function,… The only solution I have at the moment as a temp solution is to replace the `<Link>` by a real `<a>` link, causing a reload of the page.

Comment: Could you share the code for the homepage?

Comment: Well, I'm quite sure it's not coming from here, I tried to replicate exactly the code from another page on the homepage and I have the very same problem, only on the homepage. So there might be something wrong with routes maybe. I didn't mention that I have two locales (EN, FR) on this website.

Comment: It would still be helpful to see what your homepage code looks like. Also, can you show us the code for the link you click on to navigate back to the homepage?

Comment: I have exactly same issue on vercel production, with next 13. Have you found any solution?